# Font won't render in different browsers

Tags: html, css, fonts

Hey so I'm having a little font trouble.  I have this font I'm using for a project, however it will only display correctly in chrome.  When I try to switch to a different browser it doesn't show up at all and the default font-type displays.  Anything I can do to make sure my font will display in every browser heres the snippet of my code.

```
#p1{
        position:relative;
        font-family: "Didot HTF";
        font-size:120%;
        top: 300px;
        text-align:center;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

<div id="p1">
    Content, storytelling and strategy for the multi-screen, multi-channel age 
</div>
```

Comment: There must be something else in the code causing the issue. A question should include minimal code that is sufficient for reproducing the problem.

Comment: It can't be I've isolated this part of the code and I'm working on this exclusively and still experiencing the same problem

Comment: So if you create an HTML document containing exactly that code and absolutely nothing else, except the obvious `<style>` and `</style>` tags, the problem can be observed? Did you test this on another computer?

Comment: A variant of this question, indicating that there *is* other code involved, has now been posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24758125/font-face-troubles-with-custom-font so this question should be closed as duplicate *and* off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

if you use non-standard fonts in a project I advise you to use @ font-face, it needs to use the service to transfer a default font in web font, web font ready to connect like this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SegoePrint';
    src: url('../fonts/SegoePrint.eot?') format('eot'),
         url('../fonts/SegoePrint.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/SegoePrint.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/SegoePrint.svg#SegoePrint') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: Its still not working for me,  I'm pretty new to CSS am I doing something wrong here                                              @font-face {
      font-family: 'DidotHTF';
   src: url('DidotHTF.eot?') format('eot'),
            url('DidotHTF.woff') format('woff'),
            url('DidotHTF.ttf')  format('truetype'),
            url('DidotHTF.svg#DidotHTF') format('svg');
 }

Comment: maybe ... you need to understand that the web using non-standard fonts, ie those fonts that you do not meet the OS on this if you are not used to design standart fonts connect them in a way that I described to you, advise on this topic read the documentation which the Internet is full