# @font-face troubles with custom font

Tags: html, css, fonts

Hey so I asked a question to this a little b it ago but didn't get anywhere so I though it would be a good idea to post the whole snap of the code since I'm new to this.  Anyway, I was wondering if anyone can tell what I'm doing wrong here.  I'm using a custom font for a project but it only seems to render in chrome.  I've tried using the @fontface structure but its still not working.  Any help will be extremely appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html >

<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Fire House Home</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    @font-face {
         font-family: 'Didot HTF';
         src: url('DidotHTF.eot?') format('eot'),
              url('DidotHTF.woff') format('woff'),
              url('DidotHTF.ttf')  format('truetype'),
              url('DidotHTF.svg#DidotHTF') format('svg');
    }    
    #p1{
        position:relative;
        font-family: "Didot HTF";
        font-size:120%;
        top: 300px;
        text-align:center;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }



    -->  

    </style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="p1">
    Content, storytelling and strategy for the multi-screen, multi-channel age 
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want to clarify you specify the path to the folder with the font?

Comment: Check in browser console if font files are accessed without error.

Comment: You should refer to your previous question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24755149/font-wont-render-in-different-browsers. It would have been better to improve the old question instead of spawning a copy. Anyway, the question still lacks sufficient information. E.g., where did you get the font from, how did you generate the font files, and how did you double-check that the font files are available at the addresses specified?

Comment: I got the font from http://www.typography.com/fonts/didot/styles/ .   I tried generating the font files with font squirrel bit it won't let me add the font file.  I think because it doesn't have an extension the downloaded file I got from typography is named DidotHTF-11MediumItalic and has not ttf, woff or other extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and so you see the need to generate web font [web font generator](http://www.web-font-generator.com/) put in projects folder fonts and @ font-face to specify the path to the font
like this

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SegoePrint';
    src: url('../fonts/SegoePrint.eot?') format('eot'),
         url('../fonts/SegoePrint.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/SegoePrint.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/SegoePrint.svg#SegoePrint') format('svg');
}
```

Comment: I tried using a web font generator, unfortunately, the various ones I have tried won't let me upload the font because it doesn't have an extension. The font file just looks like this DidotHTF-11MediumItalic

Comment: Thanks for all your help, but for some reason its still not working!  I downloaded the zip and put all of the webfont files in a folder called fonts and moved that into the folder with my html file so now my folder contains fonts and the html document and my code now looks like:

Comment: @font-face {
 font-family: 'Didot-HTF-M11-Medium-Ital';
 src: url('../fonts/Didot-HTF-M11-Medium-Ital.eot?') format('eot'), 
      url('../fonts/Didot-HTF-M11-Medium-Ital.woff') format('woff'), 
      url('../fonts/Didot-HTF-M11-Medium-Ital.ttf')  format('truetype'),
      url('../fonts/Didot-HTF-M11-Medium-Ital.svg#Didot-HTF-M11-Medium-Ital') format('svg');
 }                                                         #p1{
     position:relative;
     font-family: "Didot-HTF-M11-Medium-Ital";
     font-size:120%;
  top: 300px;
  text-align:center;
  white-space: nowrap;
 }

Comment: fonts folder should be located in the root of the project